# Background Width jQuery Specification Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a web page where the background of my page changes depending on the hour. I want the background image to always be the full width of the page, so I am trying to set it to be 100%, but it doesn't seem to be working. Is there some part of the code that's written incorrectly? Do I need to implement something else?

```css
body {
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
#demo {
  color: white;
}
#txt {
  color: white;
  float: left;
  font-family: OpenSans;
  font-size: 90px;
  margin: 20px;
}
#weather {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-family: OpenSans;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Blooming Time And Temperature</title>
    <link href="css/format.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <script>
          function startTime() {
        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
          moment().format("hh:mm A");
        var t = setTimeout(startTime, 1000);
        var hour = moment().hour()
      }
    </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

              function changeBackground(){
              var hour = new Date().getHours();
              if(hour > 7 && hour <= 12)
              {
                 // It's morning
                 $('body').css('background', 'url(sequence/1.jpg) no-repeat').width('100%');
              }
              else if(hour > 12 && hour < 18)
              {
                 // It's noon
                 $('body').css('background', 'url(sequence/2.jpg) no-repeat').width('100%');
              }
              else if(hour > 19 && hour < 21)
              {
                 // It's noon
                 $('body').css('background', 'url(sequence/3.jpg) no-repeat').width('100%');
              }
              else
              {
                  // It's night
                  $('body').css('background', 'url(sequence/4.jpg) no-repeat').width('100%');
              }
          }
   changeBackground(); // invoke for the first time manually
   setInterval(changeBackground, 1000 * 60 * 60);

        });
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.simpleWeather/3.1.0/jquery.simpleWeather.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $.simpleWeather({
          location: 'Brooklyn, NY',
          woeid: '',
          unit: 'f',
          success: function(weather) {
            html = '<p>'+weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</p>';
            html += '<div id="city">'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</div>';

            $("#weather").html(html);
          },
          error: function(error) {
            $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="startTime()"">
    <div id="txt"></div>
    <div id="weather"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try removing the margin attributes on the body tag in your CSS, and set `background-size: cover` on the body tag there. Then in your changeBackground function, you mightn't need the `.width(100%);` method, since the width shouldn't change when you swap out the background images?

Comment: That didn't seem to work unfortunately. Nothing I do in CSS seems to effect the image. :( Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: It could be that the `.css('background'...)` code is overriding your background size styling. Maybe try changing each of those lines to:

`$('body').css('background-image', 'url(sequence/1.jpg)');`

Then pop in `background-size: cover;` to the body tag CSS as before, along with `background-repeat: no-repeat;`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are putting the background image on the `body` and you have this css property, it won't do.

```
body {
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
```

Make the property

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
```